# Convert code from asp to aspx using Else IF in Eval

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, eval

I have a code from .asp  and want to convert it to .aspx, how to convert it in proper way for the code. the code are shown below. thank you.

```
if isnull(RSTrx("notVerifyRsn")) and not isnull(RSTrx("notVerifyRsn")) then
                                reason = trim(RSTrx("notAppRsn"))
                            elseif not isnull(RSTrx("notVerifyRsn")) and isnull(RSTrx("notVerifyRsn")) then
                                reason = trim(RSTrx("notVerifyRsn"))
                            end if
```

Comment: you can add a functio with a public scope and call it in the page, that will be better

Comment: you can refer this link : http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/asp-to-aspnet/overview